# My Processing sketch in OOP doesn't work

Tags: oop, processing

The following code is intended to draw a blue background and three moving shapes (circle, square, triangle) to the screen. However, the code is written in object-oriented programming, and something is wrong as my sketch works perfectly in Java mode of Processing IDE but fails to work in OpenProcessing. The code compiles perfectly. I assume I'm doing something incorrect with the OOP somehow. Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

```java
Circle circle = new Circle(PI,200,400,400);
Square square = new Square(100,100);
Triangle triangle = new Triangle(400,400);
void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(120);
}
void draw() {
  background(0,0,255);
  circle.drawCircle();
  square.drawSquare();
  triangle.drawTriangle();
}
void shadeOfOrange(int x) {
  fill(255,128-x,0);
}
class Circle {
  float offsetX = 0;
  float offsetY = 0;
  float circleScalar;
  float angle;
  float circleStep = 0.005;
  Circle(float initialAngle,float radius,float offsetX,float offsetY) {
    angle = initialAngle;
    circleScalar = radius;
    this.offsetX = offsetX;
    this.offsetY = offsetY;
  }
  void drawCircle() {
    pushMatrix();
    for(int i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
      shadeOfOrange(i);
      float x1 = offsetX + circleScalar*cos(angle);
      float y1 = offsetY + circleScalar*sin(angle);
      ellipse(x1,y1,i,i);
    }
    popMatrix();
    this.incrementAngle();
  }
  void incrementAngle() {
    angle += circleStep;
    if(angle >= 2*PI)
      angle -= 2*PI;
  }
}
class Square {
  boolean right = true;
  boolean down = false;
  boolean left = false;
  boolean up = false;
  int transX = 0;
  int transY = 0;
  int offsetX = 0;
  int offsetY = 0;
  Square(int offsetX,int offsetY) {
    this.offsetX = offsetX;
    this.offsetY = offsetY;
  }
  void drawSquare() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(transX,transY);
    for(int i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
      shadeOfOrange(i);
      rect(offsetX,offsetY,i,i);
    }
    popMatrix();
    this.adjustTranslation();
  }
  void adjustTranslation() {
    if(right) {
      transX++;
      if(transX == 600) {
        right = false;
        down = true;
      }
    }
    else if(down) {
      transY++;
      if(transY == 600) {
        down = false;
        left = true;
      }
    }
    else if(left) {
      transX--;
      if(transX == 0) {
        left = false;
        up = true;
      }
    }
    else if(up) {
      transY--;
      if(transY == 0) {
        up = false;
        right = true;
     }
    }
  }
}
class Triangle {
  float triangleScalar = 1;
  boolean scalarUp = true;
  float triangleStep = 0.01;
  int offsetX = 0;
  int offsetY = 0;
  Triangle(int offsetX,int offsetY) {
    this.offsetX = offsetX;
    this.offsetY = offsetY;
  }
  void drawTriangle() {
    pushMatrix();
    for(int i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
      shadeOfOrange(i);
      float vert1x = offsetX;
      float vert1y = offsetY - (sqrt(3)/3)*i*triangleScalar;
      float vert2x = offsetX - i/2 * triangleScalar;
      float vert2y = offsetY + (sqrt(3)/6)*i*triangleScalar;
      float vert3x = offsetX + i/2 * triangleScalar;
      float vert3y = offsetY + (sqrt(3)/6)*i*triangleScalar;
      triangle(vert1x,vert1y,vert2x,vert2y,vert3x,vert3y);
    }
    popMatrix();
    this.incrementScalar();
  }
  void incrementScalar() {
    if(triangleScalar > 2.0)
      scalarUp = false;
    else if(triangleScalar < 0.5)
      scalarUp = true;

    if(scalarUp)
      triangleScalar += triangleStep;
    else
      triangleScalar -= triangleStep;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric and welcome to StackOverflow ! Can you edit your question and add any error/log you see ? It would help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenProcessing uses Processing.js, which is JavaScript, and you have to be careful about naming things in JavaScript. For example, you can't have variables with the same name as functions.

Specifically, your `triangle` variable clashes with the `triangle()` function. Basically, you're replacing the `triangle()` function with your `triangle` variable, so when JavaScript tries to call the `triangle()` function, it gets your `triangle` variable instead, and you get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: triangle is not a function
```

Note that this is shown in the JavaScript console. You should really get into the habit of checking this for errors. You can get to it by pressing the `F12` key in most browsers.

The easy solution to the problem is to simply rename your `triangle` variable (along with any other variables with clashing names) so that it no longer clashes.

More info can be found [here](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#variablenamingcare).